# .each() method in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add data to a set of images that increments after each element. Jquery in Action has this code:

```
settings.thumbnails$ = this.filter('img');
settings.thumbnail$.each(function(n) {
$(this).data('photo-index',n);
```

The book says that this use of .each() will add a unique number to each element that records its position in a list. I don't understand how this would be the case, since the value `n` attached to the 'photo-index' will be the same for each iteration...

Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = ['foo','bar','foobar','baf','woot'];
$.each(data,function(iterator,element){
  console.log(iterator+'. '+element);
});
```

You're missing that `.each` has two arguments it can take in the function call.

So, to apply it to your code:

```
settings.thumbnails$ = this.filter('img');
settings.thumbnails$.each(function(i,e) { // add back the iterator (i)
  $(this).data('photo-index',i); // reference it here
});
```

*You also reference "settings.thumbnail$" (singular) in the `.each` call which may be the issue, but I don't know what you're going for.*

Alternatively, you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and use it's native index to assign with:

```
settings.thumbnails$.each(function(i,e){
  $(this).data('photo-index',$(this).index());
});
```

Comment: In `.map()`, the first parameter is the index, just like in `.each()`, so `$(i)` won't do what you want. And you're not returning anything from `.map()`, so you're really just using it like `.each()`. EDIT: I see you updated to use `this` instead. EDIT2: This comment is obsolete. ;o)

Comment: @patrickdw: You're right, I'm a little brain-dead this afternoon. I'm getting the Friday jitters and not thinking clearly; a sure flag that it's quitting time. ;p Good looking out though, and fixed the demo.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery each() will populate the first argument with the index of the current iteration in the list, so each element of settings.thumbnail$ will get assigned a unique `n` to `$(this).data('photo-index', n)`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, the `this` keyword refers to an individual element which you're iterating over. `n` will be the index. So if you have 3 `img` elements, the function will be called 3 times, with `n` from 0 to 2 and each current element bound to `this`. You can also access the element via a second argument to the function: `function(n, element) { $(element).data("photo-index", n); }`

Documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` function returns an array with the image elements. The *unique number* probably does refer to the array index. So `n` is the index of your image in the result of the call to `filter`.

This index stays the same as long as you're adding images after the currently present images in the document.