# ajax loop over data in jquery

Tags: jquery

It is possible to loop over all value I get back from jquery ajax call?

below is what I'm trying to do...

```
if ($(data.DATA).length == 1) {

   loop ALL data.DATA {
        get data.DATA.ID
   }



}
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do  you want to achieve?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126171/each-method-in-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(data.DATA, function(index, value){
    alert(value.ID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
for (var d in data) {
    alert(data[d]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a jQuery DOM object then:

```
if ($(data.DATA).length == 1) {
    $(data.DATA).each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
    });
}
```